# BlackBerry 10 Architecture

Tags: blackberry, architecture, native

I am looking for information about BlackBerry 10 architecture. I need this for my Master publication so it should be true information and it should be scientific fact. I compare Android, Windows Phone and BB 10. On Windows Phone official page I found this information, on Android too, but with BB 10 I have big problem. 
The next question is : which platform i should use to develop on BB 10? I mean easy functionality like: play sound, display test, notification? On BB 10 we can use few technology, but which one is native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.sys_arch/topic/about.html 
I don't know uf this is what you are searching for but it sounds a lot like the os architecture? At least most parts of it...

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Thanks a lot. Few week ago I couldnt find this information on this page. I guess that is update information. And what about native language? Which one is the best way to develope e.g notification?

Comment: There is no best way to develop for BlackBerry 10, all depends on the type of application you wish to build.  It is [POSIX system](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.prog/topic/posix_conformance.html) so supports C/C++ development.  

For notifications, Blackberry 10 has Push Services where you can leverage [Push Services](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/10/blackberry-push/)